# There is No spacing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I uploaded font-awesome css file in my VS code editor and the code is all white. [the all white code of my css file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPs5E.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The 'no spacing' means the file is minified. The 'all white' means the file is probably too big for vscode to colorize.

You can make the file look prettier by doing [`Shift+Alt+F` https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_formatting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_formatting)

Comment: it really worked